# laravel localhost showing old project

Tags: laravel

I started learning laravel recently. My first project was in documents/projects/test/blog, and was working fine. I was able to follow tutorial on youtube just fine.

Now, I'm trying to make new project, but this time in c/xampp/htdocs/projects/blog, and I got all the files there for laravel, but when I launch laravel server, it still points me to my first project.

And yes, I am in correct folder when I do "php artisan serve"

Comment: use localhost:yourport as like localhost:8000
Another solution : You can use laragon which is very good package for develop laravel application.

Comment: I use localhost:8000 and it goes to my first project.. why? :(

Comment: use `localhost::8000/yourProjectFolder`

Comment: Which directory are you in when you do `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Are you using Homestead as your web server? The XAMPP reference makes me suspicious.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5vXC6Ga.png I am in folder which contains all laravel files and folders. I run serve command, and server launches, and when I go to localhost:8000, I go to other project, not this one :(

Comment: I have this in xampp cause I have all my projects there.. Im not running xampp tho

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do Ctrl + Shift + R (Hard refresh) on your browser?

Answer (score 1):

PHP cli is running behind in process, end that task using Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the server was still open when I checked the task manager.
Try `End task` on those. If you are having hard time finding them then restarting your device might work. Good Luck.